# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, storage, volume

I am downloading some files from S3 to my EC2 instance. I got this error `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device` so I created a new 100 GiB volume and I attached it to the EC2 instance but the same error persists as if the new volume is not being used.

I am using an Amazon Linux image.

lsblk:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0    8G  0 disk
xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk
```

df -h:

```
devtmpfs        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G  420K  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  8.0G   63M 100% /
tmpfs           393M     0  393M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Your 100G disk `xvdf` is not mounted anywhere.

Comment: What should I add to mount it ?

Comment: [Make an Amazon EBS volume available for use on Linux - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)

Comment: Another option is to simply increase the space of the existing Amazon EBS disk and then reboot the instance. It should recognise the larger disk automatically.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein   I tried to increase EBS disk but I did not find how

Comment: You can increase the size of an Amazon EBS Volume by using the "Modify" command. See: [Request modifications to your EBS volumes - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html)